# What dialect is spoken in Torella del Sannio?

Tags: history, regional

My family comes from Torella del Sanio, in the Campobasso province of Molise. I learned standard Italian in school and I have difficulty understanding my family when they speak the dialect.

Is there a name for this dialect, or any way to find out more about its history and how its grammar and vocabulary differ from standard Italian?

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to clarify whether your relatives belong to any linguistic minority in Molise (Croatian? Albanese?): in that case that would not be Italian at all. Otherwise, chances are that your relatives speak Molisan dialect, probably Campobassan dialect.

You can read something very basic [here](http://www.promolise.it/dialetti.php) and [here](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetto_molisano): it is probably a starting point (since the differences with Italian are very many, I will not summarise them here, please refer to the sources cited at the links above).